# For what parameter does the abbreviation MA stand for?

Tags: orbital-elements

In the sentence:
"We added a Keplerian model with P = 120.713 days, m = 14.629M<sub>⊕</sub>, e = 0.0448, ω = 251.36°, and MA=216.88° plus Gaussian noise with rms=5.9696 ms<sup>-1</sup>."

P is the orbital period, e the eccentricity,... But what is MA? I'm guessing its the mean anomaly, but the mean anomaly is a time-dependent variable which (for my understanding) does not make sense in this context...

Quote is from https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/719/1/890 (page 24).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It stands for mean anomaly. The start of section 3 gives the epoch.

> The epoch for all the fits in this work is
> JD 2450602.093.